# How to convert txt file delimited by pipe symbol to xls file in Java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I need to have the data from a csv file into excel in selenium.

Having csv file in format like:

```
PERIOD|EMPLID|EMPL_RCD|HOME HOST|NAME|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|FTE|EMPL_STATUS
5/04/2018|78787|0|Home|mandon|steven|jabobs|1|A
6/04/2018|78789|0|Home|stacy|carvin|tans|1|A
11/04/2018|17892|0|Home|neel|harvis|bammer|1|A
```

Need to have this data in excel like shown in image:

[image]

**EDIT** My attempt at creating an Excel file

I am using the below code for generating the (.xls) file from csv file with pipe symbol delimiter as shown in the image

[image]

but is is giving `java.lang.NullPointerException` after reading first line.

```
public class DelimitedToXls {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allRowAndColData = null;
        ArrayList<String> oneRowData = null;
        String fName = "C:\\input.csv";
        String currentLine;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int i = 0;
        allRowAndColData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while ((currentLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
            oneRowData = new ArrayList<String>();
            String oneRowArray[] = currentLine.split(";");
            for (int j = 0; j < oneRowArray.length; j++) {
                oneRowData.add(oneRowArray[j]);
            }
            allRowAndColData.add(oneRowData);
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }

     try {
         HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
         for (int i = 0; i < allRowAndColData.size(); i++) {
           ArrayList<?> ardata = (ArrayList<?>) allRowAndColData.get(i);
           HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0 + i);
           for (int k = 0; k < ardata.size(); k++) {
                System.out.print(ardata.get(k));
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) k);
                cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(k).toString());
           }
           System.out.println();
         }
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream("C:\\outputFile.xls");
       workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
       fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You just need to replace the pipes by commas, then you can open it with excel

Comment: How is this related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you Debanjan for the inputs. Actually I am able to read the csv file but I need to put this data into excel with proper mapping like 1st row should be the header(PERIOD EMPLID) and subsequent rows should be the values mapped with each column(5/04/2018 78789) like shown in the image and this with the help of code and not by opening the text file in excel directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 main options:

- Open it directly with Excel and setting the delimiter as `|` (pipe)
- Rewrite it as a valid CSV (Comma-Separated Values) file (ie, replace the pipes by commas)
- Write the content of the file into a proper Excel file.

> **Option 1 - Open it directly with Excel**

See Fabrizio's answer.

> **Option 2 - Rewrite it as a valid CSV file**

**If you are sure you have no commas in your file**

You just need to replace all occurrences of `|` by `,` to have a valid csv (Comma-Separated Values) file. Then you can open it with Excel.

```
String fileName = "/path/to/your/file/textFile.txt";
String csvFileName = "/path/to/your/file/csvFile.csv";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
     Writer writer = new FileWriter(csvFileName)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.append(line.replaceAll("[|]", ","));
        writer.append("\n");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code changes the content of your file to

```
PERIOD,EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,HOME HOST,NAME,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,FTE,EMPL_STATUS
5/04/2018,78787,0,Home,mandon,steven,jabobs,1,A
6/04/2018,78789,0,Home,stacy,carvin,tans,1,A
11/04/2018,17892,0,Home,neel,harvis,bammer,1,A
```

**If you might have commas in your file**

You need to read token by token, and surround tokens which contain a comma by double quotes. Then replace all pipes by commas. Example, this line

```
5/04/2018|78787|0|Home, Work|mandon|steven|jabobs|1|A
```

Would be transformed to

```
5/04/2018,78787,0,"Home, Work",mandon,steven,jabobs,1,A
```

You can do it this way:

```
String fileName = "/path/to/your/file/textFile.txt";
String csvFileName = "/path/to/your/file/csvFile.csv";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
     Writer writer = new FileWriter(csvFileName)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String csvLine = Arrays.stream(line.split("[|]")) // split on pipes
            .map(token -> token.contains(",") ? "\""+token+"\"" : token) // surround with double quotes if there is a comma in the value
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "", "\n")); // join with commas
        writer.append(csvLine);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> **Option 3 - Writing to an Excel file**

You can also create a proper Excel file `.xls` or `.xlsx` using the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library. Here is an example using `POI-OOXML` `3.17` (latest version as of today) [You can get it from Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml)

```
String fileName = "/path/to/your/file/textFile.txt";
String excelFileName = "/path/to/your/file/excelFile.xlsx";

// Create a Workbook and a sheet in it
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

// Read your input file and make cells into the workbook
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    String line;
    Row row;
    Cell cell;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
        String[] tokens = line.split("[|]");
        for(int iToken = 0; iToken < tokens.length; iToken++) {
            cell = row.createCell(iToken);
            cell.setCellValue(tokens[iToken]);
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Write your xlsx file
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName)) {
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bentaye for the input. After the conversion how to get it in excel with the help of code as shown in image above

Comment: I do not understand your issue, once it is separated with commas, you can simply open it with excel. Or do you want to generate a proper Excel file (`.xls`)? If so, you need to use a library such as `POI`. I can add some code for that.

Comment: @Ishant Sure, I'll add that when I arrive at work in a few hours today. It is a short bit of code too.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ishant I updated my answer with the Excel version. Please have a look

Comment: It is working perfectly fine for me. Thank you  @Bentaye for providing the solution.

Comment: @Ishant Glad I could help you!

Comment: @Bentaye How I can store the text data into CSV? Because if the text file contains more than 36k records, xlsx is getting slow while writing and hence error occurs. I want to convert the text into CSV. Please help

Comment: @Dolly I think Option2 of my answer does just that

Answer (score 2):

You can directly open the file with excel. Open file->Select file type: text file.
Select the file, then 'delimited' option  on next window. Next window select 'other' and type | as delimiter.
Of course, save it as xls.

That's all.

[image]

Comment: Actually I have to do this with the help of script and not manually.

Comment: @FabrizioR I referenced your answer in mine, I hope that's ok with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `|` with char `\t` and store that in `.csv` file.
I have done something similar while converting CSV to XLS:

```
try{
            FileReader fr=new FileReader("TEJAS.CSV");
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("TEJASEXEL.xls");
            while((c=fr.read())!=-1){
                if(c==','){
                    c='\t';
                }
                fw.write(c);
            }
            fr.close();
            fw.close();

        }
```