# How can I read a txt that has commas and take it to an excel in java?

Tags: java, excel, txt

I have a txt and I have to transform it to excel, the txt records are separated by commas, how can I put those records in excel with java

Comment: have you tried anything ? if yes, then please post that code as well.

Comment: Excel is capable of reading comma-separated text files, so you don't need to do anything :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing data to excel sheet java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488419/writing-data-to-excel-sheet-java)

Comment: This code may help you from another quest : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798057/12194391

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This link may help you from similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798057/12194391

Comment: If I manage to create the excel, the problem is that it does not print the txt records to the excel